# Create Large Amount of Work Items in TFS Using Javascript REST API

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to create around 6000 work items via my TFS extension. I use typescript and REST API in my extension.

below is the code I use to  create work item

```
 var ops = [
            {
                path: "/fields/System.Title",
                op: "add",
                value: "Hello world"
            }
        ];

    var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Agile Git/_apis/wit/workItems/$Bug?api-version=2.2',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        domain: 'domain',
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(ops)
    };

    httpntlm.patch(options, function(err,res) {
                console.log("patch complete");
                console.log(res.body);
    })
```

I iterate details for each work item and try to create bulk of work items, with time intervals (like 100 work items batches) . But creation process fails for many of work items  with timeout problems (I was able to generate around 1000 work items). Is there recommended method to create / edit work items. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Work item batch api instead:

For example:

```
http://[collection url]/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=1.0
```

Body:

```
[
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "uri": "/ScrumStarain/_apis/wit/workItems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=1.0",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body": [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "apip1"
      },
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "uri": "/ScrumStarain/_apis/wit/workItems/$Task?api-version=1.0",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body": [
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "apip2"
      },
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-2"
      }

    ]
  }
]
```

More information, you can refer to: [Work item batch operations](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/batch)

Comment: hi starain,Thanks a lot for your response :) . One more thing to clarify,Is there any restriction on items per batch?

Comment: @Lalindu It is not mentioned in the official article, but you can test it.

Comment: Hi @Starain, I am currently implementing this I will do it as soon as complete with same.

Comment: Hi @starain-MSFT , do we need to add
 {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "uri": "/ScrumStarain/_apis/wit/workItems/$Task?api-version=1.0",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    }
for every batch element or is there method to generalize if this is common to all batch items?

Comment: @Lalindu Yes, you need to add these json objects.

Comment: Hi @starain-MSFT , I am getting "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JsonBatchHttpRequest' from content with media type 'application/json-patch+json'" error when I try to perform batch operation . Any tips on this?

Comment: @Lalindu What's the details of your request? It is working fine for me with TFS 2015.

Comment: Hi @starain-MSFT , At last it worked . We have to send it as json (not as body). We discussed same during other thread. So there need to be little correction to above answer need to put "Json" instead of "Body"

Comment: @Lalindu You mean this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856174/vsts-tfs-error-occurred-while-trying-to-get-work-items-with-wiql/42898743#42898743. The body is correct, just httpntlm provide another simple way to add json data to body.

Comment: yes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907479/cannot-create-batch-work-items-using-batch-operations-in-tfs/42922421#42922421 explained it

Comment: Hi @ starain-MSFT
Can you explain bit about below notation . Is it compulsory to define ID ? .how to determine Id? Is it possible to assign auto increment number for this?
  {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-2"
      }

Comment: @Lalindu It is compulsory to define ID, otherwise it will throws the exception. The value seems a increment number, you can generate the values programming.