# Cannot create batch work items using batch operations in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I am getting below errors while trying to create workitems with batch creation method

Error 1

```
"Message":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JsonBatchHttpRequest' from content with media type 'application/json-patch+json'."
```

Error 2

```
{"count":1,"value":{"Message":"One or more errors occurred."}}
```

I have referred to  this documentation https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/batch from Microsoft . and my question on stackoverflaw [Create Large Amount of Work Items in TFS Using Javascript REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523355/create-large-amount-of-work-items-in-tfs-using-javascript-rest-api)

I have tried to send data as below methods

- "json: x"
- "body: x:"
- "body:JSON.stringify(x)"
- "json:[body:x]"

I have tried both "application/json-patch+json" and  "application/json"(recommended as MIcrosoft documentation) as Content-Types

I have tired both Post (recommended as MIcrosoft documentation) and Patch methods

There is no references available for this error hence I have sucked at this point.What could be possibly wrong here please help..

```
public batchOperation(  ):q.Promise<boolean>{   

        let deferred = q.defer<boolean>();

        try {            
            var batchCreateUrl = this.collectionURL+"/_apis/wit/$batch?api-version=1.0";

   var x= {
        method:"PATCH",
        uri:"/VSTS_TFS_Test/_apis/wit/workItems/$Bug?api-version=1.0",
        headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json"
            },
    body:[
            {   "op":"add", 
                "path": "/fields/System.Tags", 
                "value":"tg;tg1;tg2" 
            },
            { 
                "op": "add", 
                "path": "/fields/System.Title", 
                "value": "Some Title Text "
            },
            { 
                "op": "add", 
                "path": "/fields/System.Description", 
                "value":"this is description"
            }
        ]
 }

            var options = {            
                url: batchCreateUrl,
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password,
                domain: this.domain,
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'
            },

                body: x
            };

            httpntlm.patch(options, function(err,res) {

                if(err) {
                    return deferred.reject(false);}
                else{
                    console.log("Patch Complete");
                    console.log(res.body);
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Failed to Perform Batch Operation ")
            deferred.reject(false);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to use  `"application/json"` as Content-Types and the **post** method just like the [tutorial of Microsoft documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/batch#create-and-edit-multiple-work-items-in-a-single-call) described.

Since you are using [httpntlm](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm), you can include the following options:

> 1. json: if you want to send json directly (content-type is set to
>    application/json)
> 2. files: an object of files to upload (content-type is set to
>    multipart/form-data; boundary=xxx)
> 3. body: custom body content you want to send. If used, previous
>    options will be ignored and your custom body will be sent.
>    (content-type will not be set)
>
> [Source Link](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-httpreq#post)

If you are using body, your previous options will be ignored(content-type will lose), this may cause the issue. Give a try with directly using json.

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT , I have generated json document outside  method and send it here now I am getting this error  {"count":1,"value":[{"code":400,"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"},"body":"{\"count\":1,\"value\":{\"Message\":\"TF51635: There are duplicate temp IDs in the Update XML.\\r\\nParameter name: workItemUpdates\"}}"}]} . What would be the reason for this?

Comment: @Lalindu Have add my reply in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945345/error-tf51635-occurred-while-trying-to-create-workitem-batch/42948077#42948077 . Without ID info, I also get error using this rest api in postman.