# Error TF51635 Occurred while trying to create workitem batch

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

When I try to create work items trough batch create operation I am getting below Error

```
TF51635: There are duplicate temp IDs in the Update XML.\\r\\nParameter name: workItemUpdates\
```

There is no much information available in web regarding this error.below link contains TFS errors and codes , But I couldn't find detailed information about same. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337645(v=vs.80).aspx

As per my research this issue could associate with Id notation in batch (error occurred When I tried to create several workitems without Id in batch).Can you explain bit about below notation (I am referring to  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/batch)

```
      {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/id",
        "value": "-1"
      }
```

1. Is it compulsory to define ID ? .
2. how to determine Id (which id should use first / get last id of previous workitem)?
3. Is it possible to assign auto increment number for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though haven't found some related official documentation. This ID seems to use for defining the order of the multiple work items in json content. *For example:* If the last id of previous workitem is 289, then the ID of work item with -1  will be 290, -2 will be 291 ...and so on. This opinion is based on some tests.

> **1. Is it compulsory to define ID ?**
>
> Yes, you have to define this ID, if you don't, you will get error.
>
> **2. how to determine Id (which id should use first / get last id of previous workitem)?**
>
> You don't have to get the last id of previous workitem TFS will
>   automatically detect it. This could be confirmed, when you [create a
>   single work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item), you don't have to do this.
>
> **3. Is it possible to assign auto increment number for this?**
>
> Seems not.