# Error TF51635 Occurred while importing GlobalList using TFS REST API

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I am importing GlobalList using TFS Rest API,
but getting the error below:

> The server operation failed. (TF51635: There are duplicate temp IDs in
>   the Update XML. Parameter name: updateElement).

Sample code:

```
 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(SavDir + @"\Customer_Cleanze.xml");

            try
            {
                workItemStore.ImportGlobalLists(text);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occured");
            }
```

This XML list contains about 3K records. The strange thing is that when I try to import individual list item, it works fine means list item does not have an issue.

There is no documentation on Net, however, the similar issue posted [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945345/error-tf51635-occurred-while-trying-to-create-workitem-batch/42948077)

Can someone please help me in telling what is the wrong happening here?